# Testing the model tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Please, may anyone have solved this problem.
I have two classes in my masks but do not work.

InvalidArgumentError: `labels` out of bound
Condition x < y did not hold.
First 3 elements of x:
[0 0 0]
First 1 elements of y:
[2]

Comment: Are you trying to compare `x` with `y`? Are they of the same shape? What is the value of `labels`?

Comment: Thanks for reply,

Comment: Image and mask size are (1751, 2049, 3) labels 0,255 The mask is black and white

Comment: Please can you share minimal code to replicate your issue, so that we can help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you,
I solved it by
y_true = y_true/255